# visual studio 2017 preview v2.0 upgrade "Access to the registry key is denied"

Tags: python, visual-studio

I've been using VS 2017 preview because it's the only VS I know that has Python, and it works great.
It popped up notification that VS 21017 prev 2.0 is available.
But when I try to install, pops up warning...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
Upgrade to Visual Studio 2017, which has full Python implementation.
VS 2017 Community is free.
VS 2017 Pro is significantly better (one flat fee or annual subscription)

VS 2017 Preview v1.0 was buggy.